# For any $11$-vertex graph $G$, show that $G$ and $\overline{G}$ cannot both be planar

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G$ be a graph with 11 vertices. Prove that $G$ or $\overline{G}$ must be nonplanar.
This question was given as extra study material but a little stuck. Any intuitive explanation would be great!

Comment: You probably know some result saying that a graph with too many edges relative to its vertices can't be planar. Can you show that either $G$ has too many edges or $\bar{G}$ has too many edges?

Comment: G and its complement both planar is extremely restrictive, and this problem shows there are a finite number of options.  A classification may be feasible.  I think McKay's database of graphs goes up to this size, so one way to find them is just search through the list and planarity test every graph.

Answer (score 5):

It seems the following. Euler formula implies that $E\le 3V-6$ for each planar graph. If both $G$ and $\bar G$ are planar, then $55=|E(K_{11})|\le 6|V(K_{11})|-12=54$, a contradiction.